# NginX and Rails : Subdomain doesn't not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

It's been 2 days that I try to setup NginX to work with subdomain.

Here is my ".conf" for NginX :

```
upstream mydomain_staging {
        server unix:tmp/unicorn.mydomain_staging.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/current/public;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name staging.mydomain.fr admin.staging.mydomain.fr;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @mydomain_staging;
        }

        location @mydomain_staging {
                proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
                proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
                proxy_redirect     off;

                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;

                proxy_pass http://mydomain_staging;
        }

}
```

When I try to access to staging.mydomain.fr, it works ! But when I try to access to admin.staging.mydomain.fr, the frontend is displaying instead of backend ;

Here is my routes.rb :

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  constraints(subdomain: /admin/) do
    match '/', to: 'dashboard#show', as: :admin_root
    resources :posts, controller: "admin/posts"
  end

  root to: "pages#home"

end
```

I do not know why it doesn't work ! Anybody help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you having this problem locally? You could try changing your hosts file to point at localhost so you can test `staging.domain.fr:3000` and `admin.staging.domain.fr:3000`. I couldn't replicate the problem locally with just your routes file code. Also, what version of Rails are you running?

Comment: I've got the problem on local to (server)